# cx_Oracle not reading LOB correctly

Tags: python, oracle, gis, cx-oracle

I am trying to read a LOB field in an Oracle 12c database using cx_Oracle. (Specifically, this is an [ST_Geometry](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresources.arcgis.com%2Fen%2Fhelp%2Fmain%2F10.1%2F006z%2F006z00000050000000.htm&ei=88SQVamwIoSu-AGbq73oBg&usg=AFQjCNFZIVh6qMeZV9LGN2wgTmrujS3ddA) field I'm getting the [well-known text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWell-known_text&ei=LsWQVaCXIsHZ-QHZuoDoBw&usg=AFQjCNE8Ob0KzRGS8G0LZCYiR8MKi3aWlQ) for.) The problem I'm having is that if the value being returned is sufficiently long, the cursor will chop of some of the initial data in the reading process. For example, if I run the following SQL

```
SELECT SDE.ST_AsText(shape) FROM street_centerline where seg_id = 960897
```

in a database client like SQL Developer I get:

`LINESTRING  ( 2720095.00001681 281993.71874480, 2720084.25003831 281969.81262463, [...])`

which is what I'm expecting. But if I use cx_Oracle

```
import cx_Oracle

db = cx_Oracle.connect('...')
c = db.cursor()
shape = c.execute('SELECT SDE.ST_AsText(shape) FROM street_centerline where seg_id = 960897').fetchone()[0]
print(shape.read())
```

I get:

```
( 2720095.00001681 281993.71874480, 2720084.250038 [...])
```

which is missing the geometry type. This only seems to happen when the `LINESTRING` has an unusually high number of vertices and the LOB is  very long. Can anyone think of why this is happening?

Comment: I am not familiar with .read() on the result of an execute.  What happens if you do a fetchone on the cursor and then assign the value of <fetchedrow>.shape to a string?  Which, from the work I've done on LOBs, reads the LOBs out of the database?  Also, there is an auto-convert LOB flag on the engine create.  Are you using that?  Can be very costly in performance when you don't need the LOBs though.

Comment: Hi JL, there is a `fetchone` after the `execute`, you just have to scroll over to see it :) The `read` call is to convert the LOB to a string. In my experience `fetchone` returns a LOB object. I could look into the auto-convert but I'm guessing it would be the same as calling `read` on it?